# File is not saving to newly made folder in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that created a folder by data within a pathway, and I want a cut of a manager roster to be saved in that folder. Since the folder name varies, this needs to be dynamic.

I want it to go something like this:

```
Dim sPath As String
sPath = "M:\mgr1_TCR_Reports\"
If Len(Dir(sPath & "_" & Format(Date, "mm_dd_yyyy"), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
 MkDir (sPath & "_" & Format(Date, "mm_dd_yyyy")) 
End If
End Sub
```

and saving this like:

```
.SaveAs Filename:="M:\mgr1_TCR_Reports\" & "_" & Format(Date, "mm_dd_yyyy_") & "\" & Manager, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:=""
 .Close
```

But I keep getting a runtime 1004: document not saved on ^^^ the second line of code I provided.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: What's `Manager`? Also `Format(Date, "mm_dd_yyyy")` - you have an extra "_" in there.

Comment: You debugged the value of "M:\mgr1_TCR_Reports\" & "_" & Format(Date, "mm_dd_yyyy_") & "\" & Manager   and checked it is as expected?

Comment: @BigBen Manager is a variable listed in the rest of the code. It's referencing specific names in list on a separate sheet. It references a column of managers where I only want specific ones populations.

Comment: What about the extra "_"?

Comment: @BigBen, ugh, such a small mistake. Yes, that fixed it! Thank you a ton!